# How to load next posts with Ajax & jQuery on Wordpress when button is pressed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, autoload, posts

I'm trying to make a function for my Wordpress theme.
There is a div that shows 4 posts and under it there are two buttons next and previous. Question is: How to make a function with ajax, jquery that autoloads next posts when a button is pressed in same page?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this** [tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/?fbc=b&utm_expid=3606929-104.UORT_bNFTQmA2CgLFPRuGg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F)

Simple steps to be followed.
The only different thing in that tutorial is that, that is loading extra posts. At the response time you can use `offest` with hiding old container.

Comment: Could you please post your code? Where you have stucked?

Comment: This is exactly what i want: See buttons next-previous on 'TRAVEL GUIDE'  section. Link: https://demo.tagdiv.com/newsmag/homepage-random/

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/)'s infinite scroll. Here you can find the [guidance](https://jetpack.com/support/infinite-scroll/)

Please use type = click as shown below

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type'           => 'click',
    'footer_widgets' => false,
    'container'      => 'content',
    'wrapper'        => true,
    'render'         => false,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
) );
```

Comment: I do not need infinite scroll. First 4 posts should be replaced with next 4 posts.

Comment: You can do that via the same plugin , just use 'container'      => 'yoursamediv', so that it will hide/update the next four posts. You can use this plugin as many posibilities.

Comment: Jetpack isn't needed for something as simple as loading the next post, essentially adding to the load and bulk of a site with a bloated plugin like Jetpack isn't advised in almost all cases.